# asp.net Mvc3 Razor : is there a way to compile a single view from vs2010 ide

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I know it's possible to compile all views on building the project... but I was wondering if there is a way to compile a single view on demand in the VS2010.

That way, when you change a view, you could compile this one view (instead of letting VS2010 build all views).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Microsoft did not yet add support for precompiling Razor views. But the team released a VS2010 extensions that should allow this. You may check out the following blog post from David Ebbo:

[Precompile your MVC Razor views using RazorGenerator](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html)

Here is another appreach:

[Compile your asp.net mvc Razor views into a seperate dll](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll)